# Compare two json file with empty value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two json file, and need to sync them, if changes found, below is my json file,

[image]

is parent(P) and 
another one

[image]

is child(C),

Here is my code :

```
        foreach ($localJson->PushNotification as $key => $data ) {

            foreach ($this->news as $news ) {
                if($news->pushMessageId == $data->pushMessageId){

                    if($news->Image != "" && $news->Image != $data->Image){
                        echo "new image found <br />";
                    }  
                    if($news->documentFile != "" && $news->documentFile != $data->documentFile){
                        echo "new documentFile found <br />";
                    }  
                    if($news->categoryIcon != "" && $news->categoryIcon != $data->categoryIcon){
                        echo "new categoryIcon found <br />";
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
```

The Problem is everytime when it loops, it doesent discard previous loops value, if current found to be empty

For Ex: 1st loop 1653 pushMessageId compares pdf and updates in child, but for next pushMessageId again it takes same pdf to compare, rather then taking empty field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have check your code , its look a simple logical condition and need to update current objects new value.

```
    foreach ($localJson->PushNotification as $key => $data ) {

        foreach ($this->news as $news ) {
            if($news->pushMessageId == $data->pushMessageId){

                if($news->Image != "" && $news->Image != $data->Image){
                    $data->Image = $news->Image;
                }  
                if($news->documentFile != "" && $news->documentFile != $data->documentFile){
                    $data->documentFile = $news->documentFile;
                }  
                if($news->categoryIcon != "" && $news->categoryIcon != $data->categoryIcon){
                    $data->categoryIcon = $news->categoryIcon;
                }  
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this solution may work for you.